# Python while loop that subtracts the value of loop 1 from loop 2 and prints the difference in loop 2

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to do a python assignment and I have been stumped.
For the following code:

```
import math
# adds math module

# User input

xn = float(input('Enter x (-1 to 1):  '))
if -1 < xn <= 1:
    xLn = math.log1p(xn)
    print('Python ln function: ln(1+x) =', xLn)
    print('')
print("# Terms", '   ', 'Approx', '   ', 'Error')

def L(x, y):
    x = xn
    s = 0
    s += abs((-1)**(f+1)*(x**f)/f)
    return s

f = 0
while f <= 19:
    f = f + 1
    print(f, (abs(L(f, xn))))
```

I want to get this output:

```
Enter x (-1 to 1): .5
Python ln function: ln(1+x) = 0.405465
# Terms Approx Error
1 0.500000 0.094535
2 0.375000 0.030465
3 0.416667 0.011202 
until 20
```

I can get it right for the first loop, but I need to subtract loop 1's answer from 2 and then have it print the difference to approximate (under Approx)
I know I just need to subtract each value from my first if statement to get the "Error", but for the approx section after loop one I am lost.

This is the output my code gives me:

```
Enter x (-1 to 1):  0.5
Python ln function: ln(1+x) = 0.4054651081081644

# Terms     Approx     Error
1 0.5
2 0.125
3 0.041666666666666664
until 20
```

Let me know if you need more info.
I am new to python and coding in general so I apologize in advance if this seems confusing.

Edit:
Ok after playing around with the code a little bit today I have cleaned up the def L(xn, y) making it easier to read.
Now all I need to do is to get the second loop to take the value of the first loop and add it to the value of the second loop. Then it must do this for the third and add the second and so on until 20 loops have run. 
The closes I have gotten to doing this is with the following code:

```
import math
# adds math module

# User input

xn = float(input('Enter x (-1 to 1):  '))
if -1 < xn <= 1:
    xLn = math.log1p(xn)
    print('Python ln function: ln(1+x) =', xLn)
    print('')
print("# Terms", '   ', 'Approx', '   ', 'Error')

def L(xn, y):

    while y <= 19:
        return (-1)**(y + 1)*(xn ** y)/y


y = 0
while y <= 19:
    y = y + 1
    x = L(xn, y)      # makes it easier to call in the second loop
    print(y, (L(xn, y)))
    if y <= 2:
        y = 2
        print(y, L(xn, y) + x) # bring the answer for the first loop and add it to the second
```

This gets it right for the first and second loops (see # note above), but does not continue for the rest of the loops. 
Any suggestions? 
I feel like I am close haha!

Comment: Your code for `L` does not make sense, You call it like so `L(f, xn)` but then you ignore value `f` passed in by doing `x = xn` and use the global `f` in the calculations. You also have `s` which you set to `0` increment by the result and then return, instead of just returning your result.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to define the taylor series approx for ln(1+x) for -1<x<=1. Which is ((-1)**(n+1)*(x**n)/n). I haven't defined a function this complicated before and I missed the lecture last week so I've been doing a lot of guessing. My text book has no examples of similar functions so I am pretty much lost.

Comment: I updated my code in the original post let me know if you have any thoughts on how to finish it!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options. The following are examples that don't exactly match your question due to the lack of clarity but should point you in the right direction.

```
# Format templates to print data nicely
HEADING_FORMAT = "{0:<5} {1:<12} {2:<12} {3:<12}"
DATA_FORMAT = "{0:<5} {1:<12.6f} {2:<12.6f} {3:<12}"

# Function that performs a calculation
def func(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Example 1:

```
def main():
    print(HEADING_FORMAT.format('#', 'Terms', 'Approx', 'Error'))

    # variable to hold previous value
    prev = None 
    for i in range(0, 21):
        value = func(i, 10)
        # if there is no previous then set it and
        # continue to next iteration of loop
        if prev is None:  
            prev = value
            continue

        # Error is left as empty string
        print(DATA_FORMAT.format(i, prev, value, '')) 
        prev = value
```

Example 2: Create a generator

```
def main():
    print(HEADING_FORMAT.format('#', 'Terms', 'Approx', 'Error'))

    # create an iterator
    values = iter(func(i, 10) for i in range(0, 21))
    # get the first value
    prev = next(values, 0)

    # iterate through the remaining values
    for i, value in enumerate(values, 1):
        print(DATA_FORMAT.format(i, prev, value, '')) 
        prev = value
```

Example 3: List comprehension and zip

```
def main():
    print(HEADING_FORMAT.format('#', 'Terms', 'Approx', 'Error'))
    # use list comprehension
    values = [func(i, 10) for i in range(0, 21)]
    # zip the list with a slice of same list skipping the first
    # to form pairs of each value | (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), ...
    for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(zip(values, values[1:]), 1):
        print(DATA_FORMAT.format(i, v1, v2, ''))
```

Extra:

If you need to perform other actions when generating your values then you can define your own generator to yield values as you go.

```
def ifunc(_from, _to, x):
    for i in range(_from, _to + 1):
        # maybe something extra here
        yield func(i, x)
```

Which would then replace `range(0, 21)` like so for the list comp example.

```
values = [value for value in ifunc(0, 20, 10)]
```

---

Output for each main method

```
>>> main()
#     Terms        Approx       Error       
1     10.000000    11.000000                
2     11.000000    12.000000                
3     12.000000    13.000000                
4     13.000000    14.000000                
5     14.000000    15.000000                
6     15.000000    16.000000                
7     16.000000    17.000000                
8     17.000000    18.000000                
9     18.000000    19.000000                
10    19.000000    20.000000                
11    20.000000    21.000000                
12    21.000000    22.000000                
13    22.000000    23.000000                
14    23.000000    24.000000                
15    24.000000    25.000000                
16    25.000000    26.000000                
17    26.000000    27.000000                
18    27.000000    28.000000                
19    28.000000    29.000000                
20    29.000000    30.000000
```

Comment: I updated my code in the original post let me know if you have any thoughts on how to finish it! I don't believe we were supposed to use iterations (havent gone over them in class yet. Also my # terms is the same value not two separate.

Comment: I'm still struggling to see how you get the expected output.